# Calling a method in parent controller from ng-click inside angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I have written this application

http://plnkr.co/edit/pXUCkT?p=info

here I am trying to call a method which is defined in the parent controller from ng-click event inside my angular directive

```
var app = angular.module('ExampleApp2', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/page1', {templateUrl: 'page1.html', controller: 'page1Controller'})
});
app.directive('sidebar', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            items: '=',
            onclick: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: 'menu.html'
    };
});

app.controller('page1Controller', function($scope){
    $scope.currentselection=3;
    $scope.items = [{tname: 'test1', sel: 1}, {tname: 'test2', sel: 2}, {tname: 'test3', sel: 3}];
    $scope.onclick = function(i) {
        alert(i);
    };
});
```

This method is called successfully... but the param is undefined. why am I not able to pass the param?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your plunkr is not workng. I can suggest try to call the method in the template like this

`onclick({i:item.sel})` or `onclick(item.sel)`

Comment: @KnowsNotMuch this plunker is alerting the correct value? What is the issue?

Comment: it still has uncaught reference error i is not defined. (if you turn on the chrome debug console when using plunkr). also the $scope.messgae change is not getting reflected.

Comment: every click on links is raising uncaught reference error. i is not defined. also <h2>{{message}}</h2> does not show latest value of the click

Comment: I am not sure why the error related to `i` is coming, but there were some issues with your plunker that i have fixed http://plnkr.co/edit/4z4J4K3IhRWVNl4Am54J?p=preview

Comment: what were the changes you made?

Comment: I tried to do a compare... everything looks the same... but you did manage to fix the message piece. Can you tell me what changes you made?

Comment: The ng-controller declarations were off for your each of your page. Please verify.